# how to get LatLong from marker in Gmapsfx

Tags: java, google-maps, javafx

I have a probleme with Google Maps.
I'm using GmapsFX in javafx project and made a direction from source to destination using this code :

```
directionsService = new DirectionsService();
    directionsPane = mapComponent.getDirec();
    directionsService = new DirectionsService();
    directionsPane = mapComponent.getDirec();
    DirectionsRequest request = new DirectionsRequest(citySource.getText(), cityDestination.getText(), TravelModes.DRIVING);

    directionsService.getRoute(request, this, new DirectionsRenderer(true, mapComponent.getMap(), directionsPane));
```

What i want now is to get longitude and latitude from the two markers in Google Maps so can anyone help me with this ?